# Can't find ping on macbook

Tags: python, macos, unix, terminal

Whenever I go into a terminal and type "ping X" with X being an address, I get

> "command not found"

I can't even locate where Ping is, I've looked in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`. I don't even know where it's installed.

```
$PATH = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/smlng/bin
```

Comment: In terminal try `which ping`

Answer (score 8):

On a fresh Mac OS X (10.9) install, running the `which ping` command will yield the following default location:

```
/sbin/ping
```

Let's take a look at the default $PATH values for a fresh install of Mac OS X (10.9) using the command `echo $PING` we see the settings as:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Now, looking at your $PATH variables, it looks like you are missing the following entries:

- /usr/sbin
- /sbin
- /usr/local/bin

You should be able to fix this by following these steps:

1. In Terminal, run the following command: `sudo nano /etc/paths`
2. Enter your password, when prompted.
3. Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the missing entries (1 per line).
4. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit.
5. Enter `Y` to save the modified buffer.

You should then be able to use `ping`, `ping6`, `umount`, and a number of other commands for programs located in the sbin directories that you weren't able to. If you are still receiving errors, you may need to reboot.

Comment: I did this. `/sbin` is now added in `/etc/paths`. But whenever I do echo $PATH it doesn't show `/sbin` in there. I've tried restarting the computer and it still shows `/sbin` in `/etc/paths` but not in `echo $PATH`

Comment: @magna_nz You might compare your `/etc/paths` file with `/private/etc/paths` and make sure they have the same data. Also don't forget to add `/usr/sbin`

Comment: @magna_nz Alternatively, perhaps this related answer might be of use to your situation: http://superuser.com/a/121885/339380

Answer (score 7):

If the command `which ping` and `echo $PATH` give you nothing in terminal, maybe the `~/.bash_profile` miss the default paths.
Here is the way to check and repair it.

1. In the terminal, command `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Check if there has `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
3. If not, write it (`PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`) in to the `.bash_profile` file (Steps below will show you how to modify the file)
4. If it already contains the default paths, then... check another answers

Steps for modify the file with `vim`:

1. Type 'a' or 'i' in the keyboard, you will be in the write mode
2. Now you can modify the file as you wish
3. Press 'ESC' in the keyboard, you will leave the write mode
4. Type `:wq`, you will save the file then quit the vim